# Get DOM element of watch event in Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two select boxes on my web page, and when an state is chosen from the first one I use Angular to load in the options for the second. When the page first loads, the second select box has one item, `Select state...` and after the first item is changed, I want it to change to just `Select...`.

Is it possible to access the DOM element through Angular to make this change, or must I use a full-on jQuery selector as I do in this example:

```
$scope.$watch('state', function() {
    $http.get('institutions?state=' + $scope.state).success(function(institutions) {
        $scope.institutionOptions = institutions;

        // Would like to avoid this jQuery selector if possible...
        $('[name=institution_id] option:first').html('Select...');
    });
}, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should stick to data binding as much as possible. Bind to `$scope.message`:

js:

```
$scope.message = "initial message"
```

html:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="c.o for c in options">
  <option value="">{{message}}</option>
</select>
```

when you receive your data, just change the `message`:

```
$scope.message = "select...";
$scope.options = [{o:"option1"},{o:"option2"}, {o:"option3"} ]
```

see this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DzC5V3tlEuKZHsEVxIBx?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [angular.element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) api. It uses jquery if present.

But you shouldn't access the DOM inside the controller. If you can't do this without manipulating DOM, try to encapsulate this code inside a directive.